# jquery pass 2 ajax result outside ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple working ajax with result.

```
   jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: my_url_query       
        success:function(response){                                                 
        }       

    }).done(function(response) {

        //Assuming the response for currChild1 is 12
        res1 = response;                                
        window.$vars = { currChild1: res1 };    
        window.$vars = { currChild2: res2 };    //----> How will I do this

        $.getScript( "assets/js/main/request_add_staff.js");                    
    });
```

Is it posible to create another ajax to pass another vars to the getscript

Comment: You have 1 ajax result, and what is currChild1 ?

Comment: res will pass to currChild1.. its a variable

Comment: What is the res2 variable?

Comment: I think you mean how to pass two value with one result,right? if you want to do that you need to return back the result as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I think This is what im looking..

```
 async:false
```

kinda long code.

but if you have an idea to shorten this... that will do.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php/form_dashboard/get/Senior/"+ dataid, 
    success:function(response){ 

    },

    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
    },
    async:false

}).done(function(response) {            
    res_Senior = response;                                                                  
});     

//Result for Junior
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php/form_dashboard/get/Junior/"+ dataid, 
    success:function(response1){    

    },

    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
    },
    async:false

}).done(function(response1) {           
    res_Junior = response1;                                                                 
});             


window.$vars = { currChild: res_Senior, currChildJunior: res_Junior };                  

$.getScript( "assets/js/main/request_add_staff.js");
```